# Reading a file in Javascript in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, read-write

I'm simply trying to read a text file in Node. I'm not in the DOM.

I can write to a file with this package but I'm having trouble reading from it .

I know i neead the following:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var readStream = fs.createReadStream('my_file.txt');
```

But the readStream is a complex object. I just want the variable as a string. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

If it's a file, why wouldn't you use [`fs.readFile`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readfile_filename_options_callback), which was intended for reading files

```
fs.readFile('my_file.txt', {encoding : 'utf8'}, function (err, data) {
    if (err) throw err;

    var fileContent = data;
});
```

There's even a synchronous version available, which you generally shouldn't be using

```
var fileContent = fs.readFileSync('my_file.txt', {encoding : 'utf8'});
```

Comment: It should be noted that if you plan on reading several files at the same time (e.g. in response to a request), you may get better leverage using `fs.createReadStream(...)` and processing the file using the streaming API.  Although more convenient, `fs.readFile()` will buffer the entire file in memory.